# SharePoint search: show only folders in results

Tags: search, folder, refiner

What is the best way to show only folders in the search results?

I've tried adding a search refiner for Content Type but the Content Type search refiner doesn't show up. And yes, I've added a new mapped property, as the original Content Type mapped property is not able to be used as a search refiner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use the IsDocument property: `IsDocument:0` [Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/de55253b-d21a-4c3e-b302-ce515597cdd2)

Answer (score 1):

Append this to your search:  ContentType="Folder"

Comment: Can you please improve your answer with some more brief explanation.

Comment: @AsadRefai To be quite frank, what is there to explain? It's checking if the content type is of folder (which isn't always the case, some are a weird text utf8 folder content type). It's just as descriptive as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Append this to your search: ContentType="Folder" FolderName